# Importing grib, grib2, netcdf to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, netcdf

According to [grib2 to raster? (grib2 -> raster2pgsql -> PostGIS 2.0 -> GeoServer)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25603/grib2-to-raster-grib2-raster2pgsql-postgis-2-0-geoserver), it seems like that grib2 can be treated as raster directly. Is it the so called "standard" way?

How about grib and netcdf?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/NetCDF-Coverage-Store-td5032265.html) and [this](https://github.com/davidl340/geonetcdf/wiki/The-hunt-for-the-netcdf-geoserver-plugin) for some updates.

Also, looks like netCDF will be out in Geoserver 2.4.0 See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/geoserver-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg14718.html) for information.